# Create array in php and use Jquery get

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to make a call to the database and recieve a "toplist" that is limited to 10 in PHP. Here I need to make an array and give it back to the Jquery with $.get().

But it's failing in recieving all the data with this code, How can I make this to be recieved and then do a "for each" in the Jquery for all the data that is being sent back from the PHP?

Jquery:

```
$.get("core.inc.php?get_toplist=1",
    function(data) {
        var json = JSON.parse(data); 
        alert(json['name']);
});
```

PHP:

```
if ($_GET['get_toplist']) {
    $get_top_list = mysql_query("
            SELECT * FROM ".$DBprefix."Submissions 
            WHERE status='1' 
            ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 10");

    $i = 0;
    $arr = array();
    while ($top_list = mysql_fetch_array($get_top_list)) {   
        $arr[] = array(
            'position' => $i++,
            'name' => $top_list['name'], 
            'points' => $top_list['points']
        ); 
    }

    echo json_encode($arr);

}
```

Comment: Now I just get "undefined" in the `alert()`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski It's calling `json_encode()`, so it's returning JSON. The header doesn't have any effect on the data that's returned.

Comment: In your browser's console, you should at least have seen some output returned from the AJAX request, though it is likely not in the format jQuery is expecting.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski No, it doesn't. jQuery just returns the raw data as a string, and `JSON.parse()` parses it.

Comment: You get `undefined` because the data returned is a multi dimensional array and `name` is inside an inner node

Answer (score 2):

You're returning an array, but your Javascript code is treating it as a single element. Try:

```
alert(json[0].name);
```

If you want a `foreach`, you can do:

```
$.each(json, function(i, el) {
    console.log(el.name + " score is " + el.points);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Friend your json will be like .

```
[{"position":1,"name":"name1","points":"points"},{"position":2,"name":"name2","points":"points"},   {"position":3,"name":"name3","points":"points"},....]
```

so you can not directly access it like ur way.

make a loop then access it.

```
$.each(data,function(i,val){
  alert(val.name);
  });
```

this will work.

Answer (score 1):

your php code is not proper

```
if ($_GET['get_toplist']) {

          $get_top_list = mysql_query("
          SELECT * FROM ".$DBprefix."Submissions 
          WHERE status='1' 
          ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 10");

          $i = 0;  
          $arr = array();                                                                                                    
          while ($top_list = mysql_fetch_array($get_top_list)) {   

          $arr[] = array(
                    'position' => $i++,
                    'name' => $top_list['name'], 
                    'points' => $top_list['points']
                    ); 
          }
        }

echo json_encode($arr);

}
```

just add '}' before  echo json_encode($arr);

also you are getting an array change in alert(json[0]['name']);